# Is this polynomial irreducible? $h(x, y) = x^2\ − y^3 \in \mathbb{Q}[x,y]$

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, field-theory, irreducible-polynomials, cubics

> $h(x, y) = x^2\ − y^3 \in \mathbb{Q}[x,y]$

I am trying to figure out if this polynomial is irreducible. I believe it is, but I am not sure how to show this. Any help would be great!

Answer (score 2):

Consider the ring homomorphism $\phi : \mathbb{Q}[x,y] \to \mathbb{Q}[t]$, $p(x,y) \mapsto p(t^3, t^2)$.  We claim that the kernel of this homomorphism is the ideal generated by $h(x,y) = x^2 - y^3$.

Certainly, $h$ is in the kernel, so $\langle h \rangle \subseteq \ker(\phi)$.  On the other hand, for any $p \in \mathbb{Q}[x, y]$, there exist some $r_0, r_1 \in \mathbb{Q}[y]$ such that $p \equiv r_0(y) + x r_1(y) \pmod{h}$.  Then $\phi(p) = r_0(t^2) + t^3 r_1(t^2)$; in this expansion, $r_0(t^2)$ gives only even powers of $t$ whereas $t^3 r_1(t^2)$ gives only odd powers of $t$.  Therefore, if $\phi(p) = 0$, then $r_0 = r_1 = 0$, so $p \equiv 0 \pmod{h}$, completing the proof that $\ker(\phi) \subseteq \langle h \rangle$.

It follows that $\mathbb{Q}[x,y] / \langle h(x,y) \rangle$ is isomorphic to the image of $\phi$, which is a subring of $\mathbb{Q}[t]$, and therefore an integral domain.  (In fact, the image is easily seen to be $\mathbb{Q}[t^2, t^3]$ which is the polynomials with the coefficient of $t^1$ being 0.)  That being the case, $\langle h(x,y) \rangle$ is a prime ideal, so $h(x,y)$ is irreducible.

---

(I realize this answer is a bit roundabout compared to the others; I just thought it might give some insight to see why the quotient ring is necessarily an integral domain, by showing what the structure of that quotient ring actually is.)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** If $x^2-y^3=fg$, what can you say about the degrees of $f$ and $g$?

Comment: They must be, for instance, deg(f)=3 and deg(g)=0 or deg(f)=2 and deg(g)=1. If 3 and 0, then it is irreducible as any non-zero element in $\mathbb{Q}$ is a unit. I'm not sure how to continue in the other case

Comment: It is easier to consider the degrees in $x$ and $y$ separately; consider $h=x^2-y^3$ as a quadratic polynomial in $x$ with coefficients in $\Bbb{Q}[y]$.

Answer (score 1):

*A sketch*:

If $x^2-y^3$ were not irreducible, seen as a polynomial in $\mathbf Q[x][y]$, it would factor as
$$x^2-y^3=\bigl(x-p(y)\bigr)\bigl(x-q(y)\bigr)=x^2-\bigl(p(y)+q(y)\bigr)x+p(y)q(y).$$
Deduce that $\;\deg y^3$ should be even.